# Ruby, using backticks to grep file extensions and searching file content for a string

Tags: ruby, bash, grep, backticks

I'm trying to locate txt and html files that contains "some string user input" in their contents.

in the command line the following command works perfect.

```
grep -ri --include \*.txt --include \*.html string .
```

but when trying to code it into ruby program as following:

```
s = ARGV[0]
files = %x(grep -ri --include \*.txt --include \*.html #{s} .)
```

and this is how I run my program

> $ ruby app.rb string

it doesn't work.

any ideas on how to get it to work that way?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` escapes `*` *in Ruby*, which does not need to be escaped, so the text transmitted to the shell is `grep -ri --include *.txt --include *.html filename .`. Escape the backslash so that shell gets it intact:

```
files = %x(grep -ri --include \\*.txt --include \\*.html #{s} .)
```

Comment: Great!! that worked. Turned out that I was escaping * just like what you said. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
s = ARGV[0]
files = %x|grep -ri --include \*.txt --include \*.html #{s} .| 
puts files
```

you could use | instead

Comment: That would work as the sentence too but to solve my issue that I had before i'd have to put it this way: ( --include \\*.txt --include \\*.html) 

just like @Amadan said. Thank you for the help tho